# autoimport in my vs code suggesting ambiguous import statements for rxjs operators and CanActivate interface

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, rxjs

I used rxjs map and switchMap operators in my angular service and vs code suggested me below 2 import statements to choose from. I didn't notice much but selected the 1st option and proceeded. No compile time errors. but got run time error that didn't help me anyway to understand the actual issue. after spending a few hours, I thought that the import statement may be the cause and changed it to the latter suggestion and it worked. what's the difference between the 2 imports? what are internal rxjs operators? do we use them anywhere?

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/internal/operators/switchMap';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

The same thing happened with CanActivate Interface. below are the 2 import statements. only the latter one is working. 1st one giving compile time error which is again not of any help.

```
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router/src/utils/preactivation'; 
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you have to be careful with auto-imports they've bitten me in the past as well.

Try to just auto-import from the public API's. Anything marked internal is generally something to stay away from unless you really know what's going on. Since the latest major update for rxjs (v6) they've really wrangled all the weird imports from many sources. 99% of the time you want to import either from 'rxjs' or 'rxjs/operators' for the operators.

I don't know of any settings you can tune in vscode, it's more or less just something you have to keep an eye on. If you import anything and it looks more than two levels deep I'd be very wary of using it. Generally it's a top level import like 'rxjs' or a two-level import like '@angular/router';